# Simple doubt about dual norm

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ is a normed vector space, then
$$\|F\|_{X^{\prime}}\ =\ \sup_{x\in X-\{0\}}\frac{|F(x)|}{\|x\|},$$
by definition. Then I want prove that, 
$$\|F\|_{X^{\prime}}\ =\ \sup_{\|x\|=1}|F(x)|\ =\ \sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}|F(x)|.$$
Now, my doubt is:
$$\|F\|_{X^{\prime}}\ =\ \sup_{x\in X-\{0\}}\frac{|F(x)|}{\|x\|}\ =\ \sup_{x\in X-\{0\}}\left|F\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right|,$$
so, $x/\|x\|$ have norm 1, and then can I conclude that 
$\|F\|_{X^{\prime}}\ =\ \sup\limits_{\|x\|=1}|F(x)|$ ? Or is more difficult to prove that? Thanx for the help!

Comment: Yes, basically, that's it. You only have to use the linearity of $F$;

Comment: @Berci the first equality is trivial but the second requires proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We find the desired result by
\begin{array}\\
\|F\|_{X^{\prime}}\ = \sup_{x\in X-\{0\}}\frac{|F(x)|}{\|x\|}=\sup_{x\in X-\{0\}}\left|F\left(\frac{x}{\|x\|}\right)\right|=\sup_{||x||=1}|F(x)|&\leq \sup_{0<||x||\leq1}|F(x)|\\&\leq \sup_{0<||x||\leq1}\frac{|F(x)|}{\|x\|}\\&\leq \sup_{x\in X-\{0\}}\frac{|F(x)|}{\|x\|}\\&=\|F\|_{X^{\prime}}
\end{array}

Comment: Nice, +1. Minor detail: you should take the sup over $0<\|x\|\leq 1$ to avoid $0$ division in your second inequality.

Comment: @julien thanks for the precious detail.

Comment: Sami Ben Romdhane and julien, thanks both so much :)

Comment: @ShanaKugimiya you're welcome:)